React/JS async operations within onChange callback changes event data
I just ran into this curious behavior that I can't explain. In my React app I have the following onChange callback for when value changes within an input.
const onInputChange = useCallback(async (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    console.log('before: ' + e.target.value);

    await doAsyncThing();

    console.log('after: ' + e.target.value);
}, [])

And I noticed that after calling doAsyncThing() the contents of e.target.value are gone; this value is now just an empty string whereas before it was something else. It will show something like:
before: a
after:

Is there some nuance I am missing with doing asynchronous operations within onChange callbacks?
The implementation of doAsyncThing here does not matter. It is not manipulating anything. It does nothing - which is why I was  confused to see this.
async function doAsyncThing(text: string): Promise<string[]> {
    return []
}

Here is a reproducer that showcases the behavior.

It looks like doSomeASyncThing or some other function is changing the value of the input.

Would be extremely helpful if you share what the doAsyncThing() is doing under the hood.

@ControlAltDel I can assure you it is not. The implementation of doAsyncThing does not matter here, though I updated the post with it for reference.

@Sarkis Updated with a minimal example to reproduce the behavior here. I did not include it because I was certain the implementation did not matter - and indeed it does not. See the example code at the link for reference.

React explicitly nulls out the properties of the synthetic event like your e after the async/await handler has completed. This is done to avoid memory leaks by preventing references to DOM nodes or other objects that could keep them alive unnecessarily. Therefore, after an asynchronous operation - such as your doAsyncThing() - you find that the event object's properties are reset.
If you want to preserve the e.target.value invoke a high-level const at first.
A good article covering this topic

Not necessarily. My use-case here is simply to save the value of the input into a state variable - which I can do before the asynchronous call. I just noticed that if I move the setValue to the end that it would not update properly. Thanks for the insight and reference.
